# Where to find passive advertisements?

Tags: marketing

Imagine a soccer game. While the player is playing a match, he is seeing the billboards all the time.

I want to include that kind of advertisements in my game (obviouly, making profit). Just a brand logo, not a banner the user has to click.

Does this even exist? Is there any AdMob like which allows this kind of advertisement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found three advertising agency's that seem to offer exactly what you're searching for:

**[Reloaded Advertising](http://www.reloadedadvertising.com/services/inventory-management)**

---

Dynamic In-Game Advertising, 
Console Integration, 
Mobile In-Game Advertising, 
Static In-Game Advertising, 
AdverGaming, 
Inventory Management

**[Game Diamond](http://www.gamediamond.com/)**

---

Static In-Game Advertising, 
 Dynamic In-Game Advertising, 
AdverGaming, 
 Virtual World Advertising

**[Engage Advertising](http://www.engageadvertising.com/#/media_channels/fixed_product_brand_integration)**

---

Fixed product & brand integration, 
Dynamic integration, 
Partnetship marketing, 
Branded game publishing, 
Game communities, 
Sponsorships

---

I also found two pdf brochures that might be of interest for you (You could grab contact information from there):

- [In-Game Advertising - Initiative](http://www.initiative.com/sites/default/files/Game_Advertising.pdf)
- [Media Contacts - Advertising and Video Games](http://www.mediacontacts.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/mc_insight_advergaming.pdf)

Comment: Wow, thanks man! I only found something about IGA wordlwide, and their web is not working. I'll have a look at these, but I doubt they are interested in small audience android games.